# Matching content outside blockquote tag

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match

I'm looking to do the opposite of this.

```
<?php
// get the content
$block = get_the_content();

// check and retrieve blockquote
if(preg_match('~<blockquote>([\s\S]+?)</blockquote>~', $block, $matches))

// output blockquote
echo '<p><span>'.$matches[1].'</span></p>';
?>
```

How to show the content outside of the blockquote.

Comment: whats your real question ?

Comment: I'm looking to do the opposite of what the code currently does, which is post just the blockquotes from the content. I want to post the content without the blockquotes.

Comment: add a `^` before the pattern. that will negate it

Comment: will that get the content from the post WITHOUT the blockquote?

Comment: @user3550879 Please check if I did edit your question correctly. You need to match everything outside the `<blockquote>`...`</blockquote>` right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/477127 You can't reliably parse markup with regex

Comment: @user3550879 I leave my answer as a comment. How about use of `preg_split` which default will discard the split-sequence and return what's left. See [this demo at eval.in `$res = preg_split('~<blockquote>.*?</blockquote>~s', $str);`](https://eval.in/695053).

Comment: I'm just looking to take out the <blockquote> from my wordpress post and post everything else to the page. I can only control what is and isn't a blockquote from the admin side of wordpress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You really shouldn't use regular expression for HTML-parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/477127). I recommend using [phpQuery](https://code.google.com/archive/p/phpquery/) to solve your problem and any other similar problems in the future. phpQuery is working like [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to select elements in HTML and to modify them. In phpQuery you can just do this:

```
$markup = '<div><span>Hello</span><blockquote>Remove me!</blockquote>World<div/>';
$doc = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($markup);
$doc['blockquote']->remove();
echo $doc;
```

So you load your HTML content to phpQuery, select the blockquote, remove it, and print out the changed string.

If you still insist to do it with regex, here it is:

```
$block = preg_replace('~<blockquote>([\s\S]+?)</blockquote>~', '', $block);
echo $block;
```

Comment: Ok, I havent tried that route before. I don't have control of the content just what is and isn't in <blockquote> tags. Reading your $markup line just has me a bit confused

Comment: The post content is created in the Wordpress admin panel by the user. So I only have limited control